# Error converting varchar into int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have :

```
  when
     nazev like '%xxxx%' 
         then
          cast(convert(int,(isnull(RealEstateTax_Suma,0) / 5 / 1.2)) as varchar(8)) + ' m2'
```

and it gives me error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0 m2' to data type int.

But I think I'm not converting the result into int or am I?

Result should look like `25 m2`

Comment: How does the rest of the `CASE` expression look like? Because it returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in `result_expressions` and the optional `else_result_expression`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Better show the whole query.

Comment: Usually when this is happening it is because somewhere in the query you are messing with an integer that is causing your query to try to return an integer a la @NickyvV

Comment: If "convert(int," is not converting to int then that is some really bad naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this...

```
cast((convert(int,ISNULL(RealEstateTax_Suma,0)) / 5 / 1.2) as varchar(8)) + ' m2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed the entire query, but my guess is that your `case` statement has mixed result types.

For example:

```
case 
    when nazev like '%xxxx%' then 
        cast(convert(int,(isnull(@RealEstateTax_Suma,0) / 5 / 1.2)) as varchar(8)) + ' m2'
    else 0
end as Col1
```

The first case returns a varchar, the else returns an int. The end result will attempt a conversion to int based on the data type precedence.

From [MSDN: Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms190309.aspx):

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the
>   rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher
>   precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion,
>   an error is returned. When both operand expressions have the same data
>   type, the result of the operation has that data type.